# Format excel numbers at two decimals with python

Tags: python, excel, formatting, decimal

I would like to format numbers in excel export at 2 decimal places but only for view, and keep original values in behind as in the picture, number to be shown with two decimal places but when you click on the cell to be shown whole value. I have used XlsxWriter and add_format,and it is formating at 2 decimals but do not keep original values. Can someone suggest how it can be done and if it is posssible?

Picture example in excel:

[image: picture example in excel]

Answer (score 1):

> I have used XlsxWriter and add_format,and it is formating at 2 decimals but do not keep original values.

That can't be the case. XlsxWriter doesn't truncate the numbers that it handles in any way, apart from formatting them with `%.16G` in the same way that Excel does.

For example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

my_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})

worksheet.write(0, 0, 29.159573953, my_format)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

As you can see the full number is displayed in the formula bar.

Comment: I am trying to write dataframe and I have used the code below:  

`format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
worksheet.set_column('U:AC',18, format1)`
also:
`df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="ABC", startrow=4, startcol= 3, float_format="%.2f")`

and the result is as the first picture I have posted.

Comment: You need to put that code into the question. However, it looks like the `float_format="%.2f"` in the Pandas `df.to_excel()` is truncating the floats. Leave that out and you should get the result you want.